# Use YouTube Iframe API with Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

**UPDATE:** From @Manoj's code below and some other sources, I am now able to load the youtube player into a webview based on the Youtube iframe api. But the question still is: how can I have my app recognize when the video itself starts playing? (after the video loads, and after any ad plays).

The key code is "trapped" in the webview.

There is a nativescript-webview interface plugin that is meant to allow you to get information from the webview. If that is what is required here, what would be the correct code with that plugin to register when the video itself starts playing?

The examples on that plugin's repo seem pretty specific and different than what I have in mind here.

---

Original Question:

I have a Nativescript app using iOS and Angular. I would like to have youtube videos play in the app, and I want to be able to control the playback. So I want to do things like autoplay it programmatically and register when the video is actually playing.

How can I do this?

**More Detail:**

There is a nativescript-youtubeplayer plugin but i am not able to use that here, bc it requires an api key and some other reasons.

I am able to embed a basic iframe into a WebView, with code like this:

```
<WebView (loaded)="onWebViewLoaded($event)" requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback="false" [src]="urlSource"></WebView>
```

and in ts:

```
 public urlSource= '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZwO3PG-c5Cs?playsinline=1&autoplay=1&fs=0&controls=1&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>'
```

This loads the video. But it does not have the normal youtube controls (like no big pause button on the video)--maybe bc its overridden by the webview. More importantly, it does **NOT autoplay**, and it does **not give me a way to programmatically access the iframe info**--so, for example, I am not able to tell when the video is actually playing vs when it is paused.

The [Youtube Iframe Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) is made for this purpose, but how do I use it with Nativescript? It seems to require dom manipulation in a way that I have not seen Nativescript do before.

For example, the basic code for that is:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

But, unsurprisingly, this brings up errors, like 'can't find name YT'.

So, how can I embed a youtube video in Nativescript with iframe and control it like I could if I had a web application?

Comment: did you figure this out ?

Comment: See my answer posted below. I was able to get it mostly working with the code there. I say "mostly" because it was awhile ago and I moved on to other projects before putting it into production (as I recall, it was basically functional). There also may be better ways of interacting with the webview than the code I provide--but that should be sufficient to get people started.

Comment: before I'll make changes according to your code - do you recall if autoplay worked there ? because that's my main issue ...

Comment: I cannot say for sure as it was awhile ago, but I do recall that autoplay worked by setting the autoplay parameter to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at this for awhile, but thought it would be helpful to follow up to show what got this mostly working in my case. Hopefully there is some code in here that can help others.

For me, the key insight was putting the basic youtube code (which they give you [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)) into a variable in the TS component:

So, to start, my TS component put in the Youtube code like this:

```
exportClass YoutubeComponent implements OnInit {
        public youtubeVideoId = [ID OF VIDEO I WANT TO PLAY]
        public youtubeCode = 
          `
           <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <body>
             <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
               <iframe id="player"
                width="90%" height="375"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/` + this.youtubeVideoId + `?enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1&autoplay=1&fs=0&controls=1" 
            frameborder="0"
                 ></iframe>
           <script>
           /**
           * WebViewInterface class to handle communication between webView and Android/iOS.
          */
         var NSWebViewinterface = (function () {
               function NSWebViewinterface() {
         
          [PUT IN THE REST OF THE WHOLE YOUTUBE CODE IN THIS VARIABLE]
             ...   
        `
```

And then in html:

```
<WebView row="0" src="{{youtubeCode}}" #webView></WebView>
```

And then to interact with the webview, in the same TS component as above:

```
 @ViewChild('webView') webView: ElementRef;

  onWebViewLoaded(args) {
     let webView: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;
     this.oWebViewInterface = new WebViewInterface(webView); 
     this.nextFunction()
   }

  nextFunction {
     this.oWebViewInterface.on('onPlayerStateChange, (data) =>{
       if (data.state === 5){ //video cued
         console.log('video is cued up')
       }
    })
  }
```

Comment: tested this right now ... autoplay doesn't work ... :/ YouTube's rules changing all the time ... now via `iframe` autoplay will work only when combined with `mute` ..

Answer (score 0):

You may use YouTubeIframeAPI within WebView, create a separate local html file that can hold the scripts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          width: '100%',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZfChzw&v=1)

**Note:** You may even pass the videoId or any other parameter in query string, then parse and use the same within the html file.

Comment: on your playground, it is still not playing the video automatically and its not registering changes of state (onPlayerReady and onPlayerStateChange do not seem to be called)

Comment: And the player itself seems a little different than youtube default. For example, youtube videos normally show a big pause button in the middle if you tap them. That does not happen here. That is fine by me, but I want to be sure Youtube will not have an issue with it.

Comment: I think I'm pretty close--just not sure about what I noted in my comments here. (fyi downvote is not from me)

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the issue on your end, the code works perfectly fine on my end. FYI, I just copied same solution once I had shared on [forum](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/best-way-to-embed-youtube-in-nativescript/4402/5). Never mind about the down vote, I see at least 10 random downvotes from different threads of mine right now, seems like someone is mad at me 

Comment: Sorry to hear about downvote. I appreciate your replying to my question. I think I have figured out some of the issue--including enabling javascript in webview. I can write a summary later.

Comment: Right now I am close to getting it to work, but struggling with this: the code plays the video in the webview, and seems to control the video itself. But I need to get information out of the webview into my application. For example, what would be the code for me to call a function in my application when the video starts playing?

Comment: JavaScript is enabled by default in [{N} WebView](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/web-view/web-view.android.ts#L99), not sure why you had to it explicitly. I would suggest to use [nativescript-youtubeplayer](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-youtubeplayer) plugin if you want the player to interact with other parts of your application. If you prefer to interact with your app code from WebView then [nativescript-webview-interface](https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface) plugin should help.

Comment: I'll take a look. I want to be able to know when the video is playing, and call a function at that time.

Comment: Is there another way to get at the info from the webview? nativescript-youtube player plugin relies on api key, which incurs youtube's shrinking quota, so that's a problem. And nativescript-webview-interface plugin seems to have issues for iOS. Is there another way I can load a youtube video and register an event when the actual video starts playing?

Comment: There is no other way I could think of to communicate with WebView, may I ask what sort of issue you are talking about with webview interface plugin?

Comment: Main issue with webview-interface plugin is just figuring out the right code to use. I find the examples given so far are pretty specific and different than I have in mind. Would you be able to give example code for using that plugin to register when a youtube video has started playing? (instead of just loading and instead of just playing an ad)

Comment: If your able to give the code for how to know when the youtube vid is playing (my app is angular ios) using webview-interface plugin then I can mark your as the accepted answer. Thanks.