# How do I detect when embedded Youtube video is playing?

Tags: nativescript

**UPDATE (July 2020):** I was able to get a mostly working version of this. See my answer to the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813964/use-youtube-iframe-api-with-nativescript/63193516#63193516).

---

In my angular Nativescript iOS app, I have a webview set up to play youtube videos. Following a method similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813964/use-youtube-iframe-api-with-nativescript), I can get the youtube video to load and play automatically, using the Youtube [Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). **But how do I detect when the video actually starts playing (after it is loaded)?**

The Iframe API has events for this purpose, like "onStateChange". But, because my youtube code is "stuck" inside the webview, I am currently not able to read when events are fired from that webview.

In Nativescript, there is a nativescript-webview-interface plugin for this purpose, but I can't get it to work. I have put my code below. **If that is the way to go, what is the correct code to get it working?**

(I don't want to use the nativescript-youtube plugin because that brings in youtube's quotas, which are regularly shrinking. )

---

**Code I Have Tried:**
To get the youtube player to activate, I have put all of the relevant youtube code inside the webview. That works to play the video, but not yet to get the event of when the player starts playing. To do what I want to do, I need to have some way of inserting that code into my app WITHOUT trapping it in the webview. Or, have some way of communicating inside the webview.

To try to communicate with the webview, I have tried the nativescript-webview-plugin:

```
$ tns plugin add nativescript-webview-interface
```

html:

```
<web-view src="{{youtubeCode}}"  #webView ></web-view>
```

ts:

```
import {WebView, LoadEventData} from "tns-core-modules/ui/web-view";
let webViewInterfaceModule = require('nativescript-webview-interface');
...
export class ...{
  @ViewChild('webView') webView: ElementRef;

  public youtubeCode = [code that youtube provides in its IFrame API]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setupWebViewInterface();
  }


  setupWebViewInterface() {
    let webView: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;

    this.oWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webView, '~/www/index.html');

    this.youtubeListen()
  }..

  youtubeListen(){
    this.oWebViewInterface.on('onStateChange', (eventData)=>{  //'onStateChange' is the event provided in the Youtube Iframe API
        console.log('event data = ' + eventData)  //***this is the key part I want to work.
   });
 }
```

RESULT:  `ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.webView.ios.constructor')`

This is a problem in the plugin's index.ios.js file. If I comment out the offending line, then the errors go away, but then `nothing happens`
..

Comment: You are calling it too early, use loaded event of WebView not ngOnInit.

Comment: even moving it produces same errors. Do you know the proper updated code in angular for: 'this.oWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webView, '~/www/index.html');'     I think that is not correct, and that is a key problem here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you had done what I explained above, that can't produce the same problem as the object won't be undefined at all.

Comment: Moving the setupWebViewInterface() to onWebViewLoaded(args) does seem to get rid of that error, but the code above (with that change) still does not register any change of state in the player.

Comment: Do you see the player loading in WebView?

Comment: Not any more. Page is blank, even though console.log in onWebViewLoaded fires. This line seems strange to me:'this.oWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webView, '~/www/index.html');' This is from the angular example on the plugin page.

Comment: Why does it reference index.html? I actually have put a file with the youtube code in index.html just to be sure--but I shouldn't have to, because  the code source with the youtube code is directly in the ts. Also, in the plugin example, like my code above, it RE-DEFINES webview in the setup function. Then what is the point of ViewChild? So, my guess is there is something wrong with that line.

Comment: Then I guess your are not bundling `index.html` with your app source, you will have to adjust your webpack config to include `www` folder, [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591357/nativescript-transferring-mp3-files-with-sidekick/52592100#52592100), used to include audio files in songs folder, in your case it will www.

Comment: I can now see the player. And things seem to be closer to working. Thanks for the suggestion. But why do I need to reference index.html when I already have the code in the ts file in the definition of youtubeCode?

Comment: Just go through the read me file of the plugin, it has all the answers. Moreover, that second param is optional.

Comment: Thank you very much. That webpack note was the key. it seems to be working now. That saves me a lot of trouble.

Comment: And just one more item if you happen to know. About 50% of the vids I try to play come in "Player unavailable"--even famous ones. I see online that people recommend putting in the option: origin="https://www.youtube.com". But that does not seem to fix it for me.

Comment: did you figure this out eventually ?